# Why cant I make my <a href> links to go "inline" in the tab-content for BS nav-tabs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

[image]OK, I have a bootstrap `nav-tabs` on my website, but I can't make the `<a href>` links go to `inline`, instead they just stay at `block`. I've tried setting `display:inline` via inline styling & this doesn't work (surprising, oh wait, no it isn't because that would just be way too easy).

Inline styling works when I set the `a href` tags to `display:none` but when I set the styling to `display:inline` it just reverts to block.

Any suggestions.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#test1" data-toggle="tab">Search our funds</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#test2" data-toggle="tab">Shares for a share price</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#test3" data-toggle="tab">Published fund research</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="scroll-slide-pane tab-pane fade in active" id="test1">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Search our funds</h3>
        <p>Search our range of available funds, or go to our<a href="#">advanced search.</a></p>
        <input class="fontAwesome" type="search" placeholder="&#xf002; Start typing here..." />
        <a href="#">View my recently searched funds</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-slide-pane tab-pane fade in" id="test2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Search for a share price</h3>
        <p>Search for share price and stock information, or go to our <a href="#">advanced search option.</a></p>
        <input class="fontAwesome" type="search" placeholder="&#xf002; Search for share information..." />
        <a href="#">View recent searches</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane face in" id="test3">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Published research</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.tab-content {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4F5DFF;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  padding-left: -5px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  border-style: none;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  background-color: #4F5DFF !important;
  color: white !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.nav {
  border-style: none !important;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: #4F5DFF !important;
}

.nav > li {
  border-radius: 0;
}

nav-tabs {
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-style: none;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Do the `nav-tab` elements have any child elements set to `display: block`? Have you tried using `display: inline-block` instead?

Comment: No but I've edited my question to give you all css settings for 'nav-tabs' settings. Its actually the content in the "tab-contents" > "tab-pane" section. Thanks.

Comment: [This is what I see](http://i.imgur.com/O0UuCvr.png). The `<a>` elements appear to be inline.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mLc2kdxu/1/ here,does this help?

Comment: No, I've added an image for you to see. Yes, you're seeing the right image but where it says "advanced search" and "View my recently searched funds", they just will not do "inline". And why aren't you seeing these in yours?

Comment: @ToddGilbey, may I ask what browser you are using? Because your image differs in a number of ways from mine, and I'm sure pritishvaidya is seeing something different as well...

Comment: I use I.E & Edge.

Comment: Have you any other CSS in your stylesheet(s) besides the bit you've shared with us and besides Bootstrap?

Comment: To reduce the risk of picking up my computer & throwing it against the wall I'm going to leave it for a bit. I'll isolate the code to a new document & see if that is in any danger of actually doing what I want it to do. Then I'll know that's it's me & not a bug in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

There is a line in bootstrap that does:

```
.nav>li>a{
   display: block;
}
```

You should overwrite this line with higher specificity. Since it is already pretty specific I would use !important. Another option is simply placing this line without the !important in your css and loading it **after the bootstrap css file** in your document.

```
/*Bootstrap override*/
    .nav>li>a{
       display:inline !important;
    }
```

Hope it helps.